# Apache Arrow OutOfMemoryException when PySpark reads Hive table to pandas

Tags: pyspark, out-of-memory, apache-spark-sql, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I searched for this kind of error, and I couldn't find any information on how to solve it. This is what I get when I execute the below two scripts:

```
org.apache.arrow.memory.OutOfMemoryException: Failure while allocating memory.
```

**write.py**

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from os.path import abspath

warehouse_location = abspath('spark-warehouse')

booksPD = pd.read_csv('books.csv')

spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("MyApp") \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true") \
        .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "16g") \
        .config("spark.python.worker.memory", "16g") \
        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location) \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

spark.createDataFrame(booksPD).write.saveAsTable("books")
spark.catalog.clearCache()
```

**read.py**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from os.path import abspath

warehouse_location = abspath('spark-warehouse')

spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("MyApp") \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true") \
        .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "16g") \
        .config("spark.python.worker.memory", "16g") \
        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location) \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

books = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM books").toPandas()
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, one has to increase the memory limits. Appending the below configurations to increase the driver and executor memory solves the problem in my case.

```
.config("spark.driver.memory", "16g") \
.config("spark.executor.memory", "16g") \
```

Since the program is configured to run in local mode (`.master("local[*]")`), the driver will get some of the load too and will need enough memory.